# qr code generation in android working but not in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, qr-code

in android I use these lines of epr code to create a qrcode, and everything works .. it generates the qrcode readable by my app with the correct data. I'm trying to replicate the same code on Flutter but despite generating the qrcode, it doesn't work. is not detected. probably has some wrong data?

```
                qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("type", 1);
                jsonObject.put("content", email); // "esertest@clikapptest.it"
                String display_name = ContentManager.getInstance(getContext()).getThisAttivita();
                if (display_name != null) {
                    jsonObject.put("display_name", display_name);
                } else
                    jsonObject.put("display_name", ContentManager.getInstance(getContext()).getMerchantData().getIdentifier());
                if (scope.equals(Enums.SCOPES.COLLABORATORE.name()))
                    jsonObject.put("collaborator", DBHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getSettingsField(DBHelper.SETTINGS_TABLE_FIELD_EMAIL));
                jsonObject.put("mac", it.clikapp.toduba.network.Utils.getMacAddress(getContext()));
//                        BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(new String(Base64.encode(jsonObject.toString().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, iv_qr_code.getWidth(), iv_qr_code.getHeight(), hintsMap);
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(Utils.encryptQRCode(ContentManager.getInstance(getContext()).getOauth().getQrCodeKey(), jsonObject.toString()), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, hintsMap);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                        //bitmap.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);//guest_pass_background_color
//                            bitmap.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.WHITE : ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                        if (getActivity() != null && !getActivity().isFinishing())
                            bitmap.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                    }
                }
```

Flutter Version:

```
    Map<String, dynamic> myData = {
  'type': 1,
  'content': connection.email, //TODO check
  'display_name': "${(await contentManager.getUserInfo()).identifier}",
  //'collaborator': connection.name, //TODO check
  'mac': await Utilities.getDeviceMac(),
};

String encodedJson = jsonEncode(myData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flutter plugin to add QR Scanning capabilities in your app

refer to this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner/example)

```
 Future _scanBytes() async {
    try {
      String barcode = await scanner.scan();
      setState(() => this.barcode = barcode);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == scanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    } on FormatException{
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)');
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
    }
    print("barcode "+barcode);
  }
```

Comment: I have it, the problem is that the qrcode is not recognized. probably wrong. is there a difference between what I wrote in flutter and the one in android?

Comment: i have updated the answer see if helps you

Comment: but my problem is not scanning. but the fact that it has the wrong json data